# What are collinear lines?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I know about collinear points (points lying on a same straight line).

I know about collinear vector (parallel vectors).

But, coming to collinear lines, I am not even able to imagine them, and I can't find any definition.

Exact Question I am dealing with is:
$$\text{ [ The three straight lines ax+by=c,bx+cy=a and cx+ay=b are collinear, if ]}$$

One possible approach I did,
Collinear lines have collinear points, which will have zero area, so while calculating area, I get $0=0$ identity.

So, kindly shed knowledge upon collinear lines.

PS: Googling the exact question gives the same answer on every site. They basically add the equations, and compare the coefficient.

Comment: Probably there is an error in the question and it means to say "concurrent".

Comment: https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-three-straight-lines-axbyc-bxcya-and-cxayb-are-collinear-if/

Comment: And same question is in my book as well,

Comment: $a=b=c$ seems to give give lines which are the same line

Comment: In this context, collinear is not a type. It essentially means that all equations represent the same line in the xy plane.

Comment: i'd have inferred that the author meant "coincident lines" but had inadvertently chosen the wrong adjective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I've not seen this usage in 65+ years of looking at mathematics... which leads me to suspect it's either a literal typo, or is a sort of word-typo, where the word that was intended was replaced by something similar.

Second, literally, "collinear" would *tend* to mean something like "on the same line", or "parallel", maybe, the latter for lines themselves?

But, we should admit/note that it is too ambiguous, and is not a good (=helpful) usage.

Comment: I proceeded for concurrent and got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

These are usually called coincident lines.

When I explain this to my students I relate it to a map with a road that has different names but is the same road. Example might be the main street in my town is also called highway 64. It is the same road, but can be referenced in two ways. This is important for mapping in the Cartesian plane.

I also tell my students that they can think of these lines as co-linear lines because they know the co-linear vocabulary already. They are like identical twins.

All the points on one line lie on the other line, so there are infinite solutions to this system. This is a system that is consistent and dependent.